# SSIS PowerShell Executable not adding Date to the file name

Tags: powershell, ssis, executeprocesstask

In my SSIS package I’m running a Execute Process Task with the Executable PowerShell.exe.

The Arguments is:
Get-ChildItem -Path '\servername.com\PRD\SourceFiles' -Depth 6 -Include *.* -Recurse |  Select FullName,Name,LastWriteTime |  Export-Csv '\servername.com\ExportFiles\SourceFileDetails_$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")).txt' -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation

What I need is the current date added to the file name but I’m getting "SourceFileDetails_$((Get-Date).ToString(yyyyMMdd)).txt" it will not pull the date.

I’m not sure how I go about adding the date to the file.

Tried:
Get-ChildItem -Path '\servername.com\PRD\SourceFiles' -Depth 6 -Include *.* -Recurse |  Select FullName,Name,LastWriteTime |  Export-Csv '\servername.com\ExportFiles\SourceFileDetails_$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")).txt' -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation

Expecting: SourceFileDetails_20230303.txt

The following works from PowerShell but not in SSIS.

Get-ChildItem -Path '\servername.com\PRD\SourceFiles' -Depth 6 -Include *.* -Recurse |  Select FullName,Name,LastWriteTime |  Export-Csv "\servername.com\ExportFiles\SourceFileDetails_$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")).txt" -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation

When I run it in SSIS the following error happens.
Error: In Executing "PowerShell.exe" "Get-ChildItem -Path '\servername.com\PRD\SourceFiles' -Depth 6 -Include *.* -Recurse |  Select FullName,Name,LastWriteTime |  Export-Csv "\servername.com\ExportFiles\SourceFileDetails_$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")).txt" -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation" at "", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Try adding a period at beginning of the path. : '.\servername.com\PRD\SourceFiles' and ".\servername.com\ExportFiles\SourceFileDetails_$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")).txt"

Comment: @jdweng Still the same results.  SourceFileDetails_$((Get-Date).ToString(yyyyMMdd)).txt

Comment: hey, please format your question like this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting